# C# - How to connect to my computer's SQL Server from another computer?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have to turn in an assignment, which is a Winforms application I built that uses a database I created and stored locally on my computer. My source code contains multiple lines of

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALYSSAUSF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserData;Integrated Security=True");
```

which allows a connection to the database whenever it's called. I used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for all this. How can I be sure that when my professor runs my program on his computer that he can connect to the database?

Comment: You really can't, unless you're computer is on all the time and exposes those resources to the local network, and both of you are in the same network, firewalls are configured, etc. Your professor needs to run a local copy.

Answer (score 1):

you can distribute your database with your code and connect to the local copy

you can use "AttachDbFileName" which you can make a relative path.

You can do this via a connection string (stored in your App.config) or manually using code

as an example via connection string, from the docs :-

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

For reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It good the connection string is located in the config file, not in the code itself.

Your computer and your professor computer must be on the same network.
If both on the same network, You need to [enable the Firewall Port for 1433](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/).
After that, you need your computer IP Address, Then you just simply change the Connection String Data Source to your IP Address on your prof machine.

Comment: Is there no way to be connected on different networks? I remember for a class one time I had to connect to my professor's computer in his office while I was in my apartment (obviously different network) and although it didn't work for me it worked for my other classmates.

Comment: Also the connection string is actually in my code... I didn't really think about this issue until it was time for me to turn it in :(

Comment: @AlyssaJune When in the different network it will work as well, but it good to have static IP Address. So when there are any restart PC or Reset Router the IP is still the same. You need to take a note when on the different network there is latency on the data response.

Comment: @AlyssaJune Plenty of ISP block various ports, including the outgoing SQL traffic. Simpler solution would be using LocalDB to package the DB inside the app.